# Is CiviCRM planning a 'cloud' version of civicrm (perhaps using AWS or Azure)?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, civicrm-spark

This is a question about future development of Civicrm

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if by "cloud version" you mean an on-demand managed service. [CiviCRM LLC](https://civicrm.org/about) is currently trialing Spark, a hosted entry-level CiviCRM offering.

- https://civicrm.org/spark

This service is currently in beta, and you can sign up at the link above. From the linked page:

> CiviCRM Spark — currently in Beta — allows you to get your own installation of CiviCRM up-and-running in minutes, with a specially-customized version including the new Shoreditch interface.
>
> Spark is ideal for organizations of any size wanting to test and trial CiviCRM, or for smaller organizations and activities with up to 2000 contacts.

This offers an easy entry point to running CiviCRM, without the ongoing effort of managing a server.

Note the mentioned 2000 contact limit (as of April 2018), beyond which you could consider hosting with other providers, eg those mentioned in Erik's answer, or running your own version.

Comment: Thanks again, Chris - the running CiviCRM without paying for an ongoing server but paying for services as they're used is what I was after, but that is only a part of the 'cloud' architecture. You've given me a good deal to check out!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, what do you mean by 'CiviCRM'? In your question it is almost as if you expect a company? It is a community of committed individuals and partners, and therefore not 'planning' in the sense you seem to suggest.

In our community it would actually be CiviCRM partners that provide services amongst which could be CiviCRM in the cloud.

There are already a few CiviCRM partners that deliver a 'cloud' version of CiviCRM. I know of a few:

- https://www.civisites.com/
- https://www.civi-go.net/
- https://www.cividesk.com/

And I am sure there are more! Check https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors for a partner near you and check if they provide cloud services?

Comment: Thanks for sharing - I never knew of CiviSites and Civi-Go since they are not listed in the directory - I know a lot of people that would use such services. Though it does not look like CiviSites and Civi-Go has had much attention given to it in the past couple years. Pretty disappointing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if by "cloud version" you mean a runnable VM template. This is provided via Bitnami.

- https://bitnami.com/stack/civicrm

That Bitnami Stack offers launch against Google Cloud, AWS, Azure and other platforms.

This offers an easy way to spin up a CiviCRM instance in a preconfigured state, but requires ongoing maintenance and configuration to suit your specific needs.

It also might not be exactly the CiviCRM your org needs - depending on which CMS it uses, or which MTA, or what base OS, or any of the other variables in play.

Comment: And no, if by "cloud version" you mean [AWS Launch Templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-launch-templates.html), [Azure Quickstart Templates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates), [Google Cloud Templates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/) etc. Someone could build those, but it would be additional and ongoing work, and so far no-one has contributed that effort.

Comment: Thank you for your considered answer, your reply covers  what I was looking for.

Comment: Don't forget to [mark your question answered](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [vote up](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) (or down!) answers that addressed your question. This helps future SE users who have the same question as you.

Answer (score 2):

I run CiviCRM with Drupal on AWS Ubuntu instance.  It's been that way since 2012. So in answer to your question yes it's supported. But there's no prefab. You must build it. It's not too difficult and takes a few hours. You install Lamp stack into Ubuntu and then Drupal and then Civi. If you message me I'll explain in detail. If you understand AWS concepts then this is very simple. Matter of fact this is the ideal way to run is in cloud so you have full root access. You could also use WordPress as CMS but I prefer Drupal since it has many modules and runs better on that platform.  I tried putting Civi onto shared hosting and had several issues. This is a very cost effective way to implement.